# Format date download issue in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint, powershell-3.0

I have a files in my SharePoint site that look something like this

```
ShardReportsFull/ShardData-Full-2022-03-28-03.00.12AM.csv 
ShardReportsFull/ShardData-Full-2022-03-27-53.00.12AM.csv 
ShardReportsFull/ShardData-Full-2022-03-25-34.00.12AM.csv
```

I'm just wondering how can I download the latest file. I have tried passing a date like this but the problem is the uploaded file name format. it has a time where is not consistent so I can't just pass a date like this so I need to find a way to download the latest file instead.

```
$Date = Get-Date
$ShardDate = $Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$Global:ShardListURL = "/sites/msteams_88c7ed/ShardReportsFull/ShardData-Full-"+$ShardDate+".csv"  
$Global:shardListCSV = "C:\scripts\Re-LitHold-OneDrive\Download-Files\ShardData-Full-"+$ShardDate+".csv"
```

```
$Global:SiteURL = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/"
$Global:ShardListURL = "/sites/msteams_88c7ed/ShardReportsFull/ShardData-Full-2022-03-27-03.00.11AM.csv"  
$Global:shardListCSV = "C:\scripts\OneDrive\Download-Files\ShardData-Full-2022-03-27-03.00.11AM.csv"


Function Download-FileFromLibrary() {
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $SourceFile,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $TargetFile
    )
 
    Try {
        #Setup Credentials to connect
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Global:adminUPN, $Global:adminPwd)
 
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
     
        #sharepoint online powershell download file from library
        $FileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($Ctx, $SourceFile)
        $WriteStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($TargetFile, [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
        $FileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($WriteStream)
        $WriteStream.Close()
 
        Write-host -f Green "File '$SourceFile' Downloaded to '$TargetFile' Successfully!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Downloading File!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
    
}

Download-FileFromLibrary -SiteURL $Global:SiteURL -SourceFile $Global:ShardListURL -TargetFile $Global:shardListCSV
```

Comment: No idea about SharePoint but you could sort the links parsing the date times, do you have a command to pull the existing files like you're showing us on your question?

Comment: Could you not pull every file that matches that date variable and then sort by the last write time `$files| where { $_.Name -match "regex" } | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | select -Last 1`